# Split string in Txt files

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader, filereader

Lets assume I have a txt file called `"Keys.txt"`:

```
Keys.txt:
Test 1
Test1 2
Test3 3
```

I want to split the strings into an array and I dont know how to do it
I want that the result will be
in array like this:

```
Test
1
Test1
2
Test2
3
```

I have this started code:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("Keys.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String str = br.readLine();
    br.close();
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: did you mean to split by a space `str.split("\\s")`

Comment: First, be able to read the file, not just the first line.. Then you just need to use `String.split`. You can find a lot of example here and there.

Comment: I want to read all the file and then to split the strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store all the lines on a single string, separated by spaces, and then split it into your desired array.

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("Keys.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String str="", l="";
while((l=br.readLine())!=null) { //read lines until EOF
    str += " " + l;
}
br.close();
System.out.println(str); // str would be like " Text 1 Text 2 Text 3"
String[] array = str.trim().split(" "); //splits by whitespace, omiting 
// the first one (trimming it) to not have an empty string member
```

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps :

- read the current line in a String, then split the String on the whitespace (one or more) and you have an array which you can store elements in a List.
- repeat the operation for each line.
- convert the List to an array(`List.toArray()`).

For example :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Keys.txt"))) {

    String str;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] token = str.split("\\s+");
        list.add(token[0]);
        list.add(token[1]);
    }

}
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Note that by using Java 8 streams and the java.nio API (available from Java 7) you could be more concise :

```
String[] array = Files.lines(Paths.get("Keys.txt"))
                      .flatMap(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+"))
                                          .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                          .stream())
                      .toArray(s -> new String[s]);
```

Comment: When i Create the List it shows me this problem:
The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: Check the import. It should be import `java.util.List;`

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "Test 1 Test1 2 Test2 3";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split()` method (in your case it's `str.split("\\s+");`).

It will split input string on one **or more** whitespace characters. As Java API documentation states [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

`\s` - A whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

`X+` - `X`, one or more times.

Answer (score 0):

```
    FileReader fr;
    String temp = null;
    List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        fr = new FileReader("D://Keys.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] words = temp.split("\\s+");
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                wordsList.add(words[i]);
                System.out.println(words[i]);
            }
        }
        String[] words = wordsList.toArray(new String[wordsList.size()]);
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

try this out